Macro in excel that creates 3 tables with page breaks at the end of each table in word over 3 documents. Need this on one document
I have a macro that takes three tables in Excel that are separated by a row of blank cells and produces three formatted tables in Word with page breaks after each table. At the moment it does this on three different documents but I need them to be all on the same one. Here is the code at present;
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdTbl1 As Word.Table
Dim wdTbl2 As Word.Table
Dim wdTbl3 As Word.Table
Dim xlSht As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Integer
Dim lCol As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim Blanks As Integer
Dim First As Integer
Dim Second As Integer

lRow = Sheets("Feedback Sheets").Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row - 2


Blanks = 0
i = 1
    Do While i <= lRow
    Set rRng = Worksheets("Feedback Sheets").Range("A" & i)

        If IsEmpty(rRng.Value) Then
        
            Blanks = Blanks + 1
            
                If Blanks = 1 Then First = i
                If Blanks = 2 Then Second = i
                
        End If
        
        i = i + 1
    Loop
'Now I know where end of each table is

Set xlSht = ActiveSheet: lCol = 5
With wdApp
  .Visible = True
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add
  With wdDoc
    Set wdTbl1 = .Tables.Add(Range:=.Range, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=lCol)
    With wdTbl1
      .Rows(1).Range.Font.Bold = True
      .Rows(1).HeadingFormat = True
      .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Header 1"
      If lCol > 1 Then .Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Header 2"
      If lCol > 2 Then .Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Header 3"
    End With
    With xlSht
      For r = 1 To First
        If (r + 1) > wdTbl1.Rows.Count Then wdTbl1.Rows.Add
        If r = First Then wdDoc.Characters.Last.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
        For c = 1 To lCol
          wdTbl1.Cell(r + 1, c).Range.Text = xlSht.Cells(r, c).Text
        Next c

      Next r
    End With
  End With
End With

Set myTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
With myTable.Borders
 .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
 .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleDouble
End With


  
With wdApp
 .Visible = True
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add
  With wdDoc
    Set wdTbl2 = .Tables.Add(Range:=.Range, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=lCol)
    With wdTbl2
      .Rows(1).Range.Font.Bold = True
      .Rows(1).HeadingFormat = True
      .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Header 1"
      If lCol > 1 Then .Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Header 2"
      If lCol > 2 Then .Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Header 3"
    End With
    With xlSht
      For r = First To Second
        If (r + 1) > wdTbl2.Rows.Count Then wdTbl2.Rows.Add

        If r = Second Then wdDoc.Characters.Last.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak

        For c = 1 To lCol
          wdTbl2.Cell(r + 1, c).Range.Text = xlSht.Cells(r, c).Text
        Next c
      Next r
    End With
  End With
End With

Set myTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
With myTable.Borders
 .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
 .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleDouble
End With

With wdApp
 .Visible = True
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add
  With wdDoc
    Set wdTbl3 = .Tables.Add(Range:=.Range, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=lCol)
    With wdTbl3
      .Rows(1).Range.Font.Bold = True
      .Rows(1).HeadingFormat = True
      .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Header 1"
      If lCol > 1 Then .Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Header 2"
      If lCol > 2 Then .Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Header 3"
    End With
    With xlSht
      For r = Second To lRow
        If (r + 1) > wdTbl3.Rows.Count Then wdTbl3.Rows.Add

        If r = Second Then wdDoc.Characters.Last.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak

        For c = 1 To lCol
          wdTbl3.Cell(r + 1, c).Range.Text = xlSht.Cells(r, c).Text
        Next c
      Next r
    End With
  End With
End With

Set myTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
With myTable.Borders
 .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
 .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleDouble
End With


Set wdTbl1 = Nothing: Set wdTbl2 = Nothing: Set wdTbl3 = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set xlSht = Nothing


I tried to remove the Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add from each iteration of the Set wdTbl block but that caused it to produce only table 3 and the page break at the end of it. I feel that it might be this part;
Set myTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
With myTable.Borders
 .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
 .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleDouble
End With

I think this might be leaving the full table selected and so it overwrites it with the next table, but I can't figure out how to deselect it (if that even is the error!)

There is too much code in your question to give you a good answer, but I think I can give you some pointers.
Your first idea was good. Remove all but the first Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add. Your second thought is also good. The part ActiveDocument.Tables(1) is 2 and 3 for the second and third table.
Lastly, make something about Set wdTbl1 = .Tables.Add(Range:=.Range, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=lCol). The .Range part is the problem. That says do this for the entire document, which is okay if it is a single table in the document, but not if there are more than one.
Something like this should do it. Untested.
Dim TargetRange As Word.Range
Set TargetRange = .Range            
TargetRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd

' There must be a paragraph between tables.
TargetRange.InsertParagraph

Set TargetRange = .Range            
TargetRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd 

Set wdTbl2 = .Tables.Add(Range:=TargetRange, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=lCol)


Thanks, good to know that I'm slowly picking up how to do this. I have tried adding the above but Set TargetRange = .Range gives a type mismatch error

Also, I thought ActiveDocument.Tables(1) referred to the amount I wanted to select, no idea how I thought it could work that way

I've made a subtle change to the Dim TargetRange row.

That's worked, but moved the error to the Set wdTbl2 line and returns; Error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Just realised that I missed the .TargetRange changing to no dot. Fixing this has now caused it to revert to making one unformatted version of table 3 and error 5941 "The requested member of the collection does not exist" which highlighting Set myTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(3)

I looked deeper into it. There must be a paragraph between tables. I also corrected the first mistake (Range -> Word.Range)

I have done too. Your original version did work if I commented out my code saying With wdApp at the start of the second block. I think this was resetting the whole document as it was Dim wdApp As New Word.Application. This now works for two tables but the third causes it to go wrong again. I'll try with your new changes now too.

Please, also try the next simpler (and a little faster way) way:
Sub CopyTablesToWdDocument()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngTbl As Range, A As Range, lRow As Long, arrTbl, i As Long, j As Long
  Const lCol As Long = 5
  Dim wdApp As Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, wdTbl As Word.Table
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
  lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on column A:A
  
  Set rngTbl = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) 'each table is in an Area...
                                                                          'no any empty cell must be in A:A!
  Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.application") 'set the Word Application
  Dim rngTableTarget As Word.Range             'set this range to set position of the next table to be created!
  With wdApp
    .Visible = True                            'make the application visible
    Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add: Set rngTableTarget = wdDoc.content 'initially the content of a new document is enough
    
    For Each A In rngTbl.Areas 'iterate between the range areas (in fact the X tables...):
      lRow = A.rows.count 'extract the number of table rows
      arrTbl = A.Resize(, lCol).Value 'place the table range in an array (resizing to X columns)
      Set wdTbl = wdDoc.tables.Add(Range:=rngTableTarget, NumRows:=lRow, NumColumns:=lCol) 'add the table
      With wdTbl
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrTbl) 'iterate between the table array rows
          For j = 1 To lCol         'iterate between the table array columns
              .cell(i, j).Range.text = arrTbl(i, j) 'write the values in the newly added table
          Next j
        Next i
        .rows(1).Range.Font.Bold = True 'the format of the table header
        .rows(1).HeadingFormat = True   'the format of the table header
        With .Borders
            .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleDouble
        End With
        
        rngTableTarget.start = wdDoc.content.End      'reinitialize the reference for adding the neext table
        rngTableTarget.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak  'page break

        rngTableTarget.InsertParagraph                'insert a paragraph to avoid adding rows to the same table...
      End With
    Next A
  End With
End Sub

